# Need help merging two shapes in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape

[image: I wanna merge these 2 objects]

I'm new to Inkscape, and I'm working on a project where I want to merge these two shapes in such as way that that green shape fits in the yellow one and all the excess stuff gets removed. I have included some photos to explain what I'm, trying to say.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you want to achieve. Do you want to green shape to go into the yellow one leaving only the bottom part of the yellow, but not the excess on top?

Comment: The bottom of both shapes are aligned, and the green shape fits in the yellow one, all the excess of the green on the bottom gets removed.

Answer (score 2):

Your question isn't very clear, however it sounds like a clipping mask is what you are looking for.

For it to work, the shield shape needs to be a single closed path.

Move the green shape over the yellow, into position.

Copy and Paste in Place the yellow shape.

Select both shapes and click *Object > Clip > Set*

[image]

Comment: You are a genius, sorry for not being very clear. This is exactly what I wanted, thx alot!

Answer (score 0):

How about simply moving the green shape over the yellow and adding the missing parts? There's nothing excessive, but it needs something which connects it to the world.

[image]

Comment: I'm trying to replicate something, but thanks for the idea, I appreciate it!